# vim phpdoc multiline comment autoindent

Tags: vim, phpdoc, auto-indent

Suppose I have a comment block like this:

```
/**
 * comment
 * comment
 * comment
 */
```

And when I open a new line inside this block I want vim to start it with

```
/**
 * comment
 * _
 * comment
 * comment
 */
```

but autoindent in standard (ubuntu) vim scripts starts an empty line, like this:

```
/**
 * comment
 _
 * comment
 * comment
 */
```

Is there a modified script or a command that would make vim do that (I remember a few years back I had this functionality, but can't google that right now)?

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add this to your .vimrc:

```
set formatoptions+=or
```

> o Automatically insert the current
>   comment leader after hitting 'o' or
>   'O' in Normal mode.
>
> r   Automatically insert the current
>   comment leader after hitting
>       <Enter> in Insert mode.

Comment: @Luca at a guess, some other plugin is messing with your settings, or the syntax setting is wrong, or the planets are not correctly aligned. Without more info it's impossible to say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @somethingkindawierd you may need `set nocp` to set non-Vi-compatible mode, or formatoptions has no effect.

Comment: @richq that's one of the 1st lines in my .vimrc file

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* that PDV (phpDocumentor for Vim) handles that -- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1355

Answer (score 0):

It does that for me, and I have been looking into what does that, but I can't seen to find it. Setting compatible mode (so it acts like vi, you don't want that) kills it so maybe setting nocompatible in your vimrc might fix it (`set nocompatible`).